# PHP Fatal error - PHPMailer Undefined constant FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send email from website using PHPMailer 6.5.3,php 8.0.14, Windows 2008 r2 IIS 7. It's work normally when link to "127.0.0.1/assets/inc/contact.php" or "internal/external ip/assets/inc/contact.php".
But when I link to url "www.acett.tw/assets/inc/contact.php", There is 500 internal server error. Please help，thanks.

detail error message below:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "PHPMailer\PHPMailer\FILTER_FLAG_HOST_REQUIRED" in D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php:3598
> Stack trace:
> #0 D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php(3564): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::isValidHost('www.acett.tw')
> #1 D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php(2304): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->serverHostname()
> #2 D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1421): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->createHeader()
> #3 D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php(1316): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->preSend()
> #4 D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\sendmail.php(35): PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer->send()
> #5 {main}
> thrown in D:\acett.tw\assets\inc\PHPMailer\src\PHPMailer.php on line 3598

contact.php:

```
<?php
require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
$mail= new PHPMailer();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "false";
$mail->Host = "mail.xxxxxx.com";
$mail->Port = 25;
$mail->CharSet = "big5";
$mail->Username = "xxxxxx@xxxxxx";
$mail->Password = "xxxxxx";
$mail->From = "xxxxxx";
$mail->FromName = "ACETT";
$mail->Subject ="Message From Web Guest";
$mail->Body = "Name: name<br />Email: email<br />Phone: phonenumber<br />Subject: subject<br />Message: message";
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->AddAddress("xxxxxx@xxxxxx");
if(!$mail->Send()){
    echo "Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}else{
    echo "<b>Thank You</b>";
}
?>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68884928/fatalerror-with-phpmailer

Comment: I had PHPMailer lastest version 6.5.3 already. Am I missed something ?

Comment: Try adding : use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;  after use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;